# SalesForce Parent to Child Lookup Relationship

Tags: rest-api

Alright guys and gals I really need some help here. I am learning to interact with SalesForce via CURL/PHP and their API's. I have gotten to know the SOQL language pretty ok and feel comfortable with single API calls to select, insert, update and remove data.

However I am now trying to create a relational lookup search. I have a custom object called accounts, queried via the API as accounts__c. I then have another custom object called account_history (that is the singular and plural for it, made them the same), queried via the API as account_history__c.

Now I have done a ton of research and I understand the different type of relationships in SalesForce and what they should do. What I can't seem to figure out is how to set these up from within SalesForce and how to query it via code. I know I want a lookup relationship and have already attempted to create a lookup relationship field in accounts__c called account_history point to the account_history__c object.

The examples I find say I should be able to accomplish this with the following code:

```
"SELECT id, address__c,dob__c,email__c,first__c,last__c,phone__c, (SELECT id FROM account_history__r) FROM accounts__c WHERE Id='$id'"
```

I have tried many variations of this query based on different examples and approaches I have found but always get an error similar to:

> [{"message":"\nlast__c,phone__c, (SELECT id FROM account_history__r)
>   FROM accounts__c\n ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:82\nDidn't understand
>   relationship 'account_history__r' in FROM part of query call. If you
>   are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the
>   '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL
>   or the describe call for the appropriate
>   names.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}]

PLEASE HELP ME!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an sObject is related to another by a master-detail or lookup relationship, you can query the parent sObject field by specifying the relationship name and field name in your SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT RelationshipName.Field FROM sObjectName WHERE Where_Condition [...]
```

To fetch child sObjects, specify a nested query that retrieves all request child sObjects and their fields as follows:

```
SELECT field1, field1, ..., (Nested query for child sObjects) 
       FROM sObjectName WHERE Where_Condition [...]
```

Here is one example.

```
Invoice_Statement__c inv = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Units_Sold__c FROM Line_Items__r)
             FROM Invoice_Statement__c
             WHERE Name='INV-0000'];
```

you will notice here child object name is Line_Item__c but we are getting results using Line_Items__r (which is relationship name) in similar fashion we will query your object data using relationship name as follows

```
"SELECT id, address__c,dob__c,email__c,first__c,last__c,phone__c,
 (SELECT id FROM account_historys__r) FROM accounts__c WHERE Id='$id'"
```

Note: If you don't know what is the relationship name you have between both objects. you can follow below steps

1. Open Account_history__c object
2. Click on Master object name
3. Check the child relationship name under Master Detail option section and put __r at the end to get all records.

[image]

Comment: When setting up the custom objects for account_history I made the plural name also account_history so as not to have to worry about that. That being the case my SOQL query is identical to your example it seems. When creating the lookup field in accounts I also named it account_history so as to avoid confusion down the line.

Comment: check the relationship name as suggested in screenshot. you need to use that relationship name with __r

Comment: Does it have to be a Master-Detail relationship? I have it designated as a lookup relationship and I can't seem to find that option.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5e52UcuhjrueDhRYnRHallhMmM/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5e52UcuhjruOTVPQXRCc2dsMTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Compared to your screen this looks more accurate https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5e52UcuhjruVnkxM05mMUI5dHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it should be master

Comment: ok, I will try that then and report back. Thank you so much, been stuck on this for days! I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: @JeffAlanMidler : N.B. Best practice would have been to name the relationship `account_histories__r` - 1) It conforms to SFDC OOB relationship conventions  ('Opportunities`, not `Opportunity` for the relationship from Account -> Opportunity` )and 2) it tells you that it is a parent->child relationship due to plural nature of name

Comment: @Crop1645 thank you for the advice I have changed that to fit the plural as you suggested.

Comment: @Himanshu I had to wipe all the records in both objects to create the master-detail relationship but that is done. Now when trying to insert records I am getting an error stating that the accounts_history__c field needs a value. Being that it's supposed to link to records not yet created what do I need to put there to create the records to see if I can query the relationship properly?

Comment: Actually I may have been approaching the relationship backwards hold please...

Comment: @Himanshu Yep the Master-Detail record goes on the child not the parent and after that your suggestion worked wonderfully, thank you!